# Using "\input{}" works/fails on similar snippets of code

Tags: tables, errors, input, booktabs

(This question grew out of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612566/in-statas-esttab-omit-line-of-model-names) one.)

I've produced two snippets of code I want to `\input{}` in my main tex file. The two snippets look very similar, but it works only with one the snippets and I don't get why.

## Reproducible example

### Main tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
\begin{small}
\begin{threeparttable}
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Dep. var: } price in dollars} \\
\cline{2-5} 
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)\\
 \midrule
\input{test.tex}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{threeparttable}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item\textit{Note:} Here I'm putting many great comments about my regression setup. *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{small}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

### Snippet 1 (works for this):

```
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{price}\\
\midrule
weight      &        2.04\sym{***}&        1.75\sym{**} &        2.06\sym{**} &        4.36\sym{***}\\
            &      (5.42)         &      (2.72)         &      (3.13)         &      (3.74)         \\
\addlinespace
mpg         &                     &       -49.5         &       -56.2         &       -86.8         \\
            &                     &     (-0.57)         &     (-0.66)         &     (-1.03)         \\
\addlinespace
headroom    &                     &                     &      -675.6         &                     \\
            &                     &                     &     (-1.72)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
length      &                     &                     &                     &      -104.9\sym{*}  \\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-2.64)         \\
\midrule
Obs.        &          74         &          74         &          74         &          74         \\
R$^2$       &        0.29         &        0.29         &        0.32         &        0.36         \\
```

this **works** and produces:

[image]

### Snippet 2 (doesn't work):

```
\midrule
weight      &        2.04\sym{***}&        1.75\sym{**} &        2.06\sym{**} &        4.36\sym{***}\\
            &      (5.42)         &      (2.72)         &      (3.13)         &      (3.74)         \\
\addlinespace
mpg         &                     &       -49.5         &       -56.2         &       -86.8         \\
            &                     &     (-0.57)         &     (-0.66)         &     (-1.03)         \\
\addlinespace
headroom    &                     &                     &      -675.6         &                     \\
            &                     &                     &     (-1.72)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
length      &                     &                     &                     &      -104.9\sym{*}  \\
            &                     &                     &                     &     (-2.64)         \\
\midrule
Obs.        &          74         &          74         &          74         &          74         \\
R$^2$       &        0.29         &        0.29         &        0.32         &        0.36         \\
```

And I get the following error message:

```
D:\test\test.tex:1: Misplaced \noalign. [\midrule]
D:\test\test.tex:2: Missing } inserted. [w]
D:\test\test.tex:2: Missing } inserted. [w]
D:\test\test.tex:2: Missing } inserted. [w]
D:\test\test.tex:2: Missing \cr inserted. [w]
D:\test\test.tex:2: Missing { inserted. [w]
D:\test\test.tex:2: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [weight      &]
D:\test\test.tex:2: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [weight      &        2.04\sym{***}&]
D:\test\test.tex:2: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...       2.04\sym{***}&        1.75\sym{**} &]
D:\test\test.tex:2: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...       1.75\sym{**} &        2.06\sym{**} &]
D:\test\test.tex:3: Misplaced \cr. [            &]
D:\test\test.tex:3: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [            &]
D:\test\test.tex:3: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [            &      (5.42)         &]
D:\test\test.tex:3: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...     (5.42)         &      (2.72)         &]
D:\test\test.tex:3: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...     (2.72)         &      (3.13)         &]
D:\test\test.tex:4: Misplaced \cr. [\addlinespace]
D:\test\test.tex:4: Misplaced \noalign. [\addlinespace]
D:\test\test.tex:5: Missing $ inserted. [m]
D:\test\test.tex:5: Missing } inserted. [m]
D:\test\test.tex:5: Missing } inserted. [m]
D:\test\test.tex:5: Missing } inserted. [m]
D:\test\test.tex:5: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. [m]
D:\test\test.tex:5: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [mpg         &]
D:\test\test.tex:5: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [mpg         &                     &]
D:\test\test.tex:5: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...                    &       -49.5         &]
D:\test\test.tex:5: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...      -49.5         &       -56.2         &]
D:\test\test.tex:6: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [            &]
D:\test\test.tex:6: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [            &                     &]
D:\test\test.tex:6: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...                    &     (-0.57)         &]
D:\test\test.tex:6: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...    (-0.57)         &     (-0.66)         &]
D:\test\test.tex:7: Misplaced \noalign. [\addlinespace]
D:\test\test.tex:8: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [headroom    &]
D:\test\test.tex:8: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [headroom    &                     &]
D:\test\test.tex:8: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...                    &                     &]
D:\test\test.tex:8: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...                    &      -675.6         &]
D:\test\test.tex:9: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [            &]
D:\test\test.tex:9: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [            &                     &]
D:\test\test.tex:9: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...                    &                     &]
D:\test\test.tex:9: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...                    &     (-1.72)         &]
D:\test\test.tex:10: Misplaced \noalign. [\addlinespace]
D:\test\test.tex:11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [length      &]
D:\test\test.tex:11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [length      &                     &]
D:\test\test.tex:11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...                   &                     &]
D:\test\test.tex:11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...                   &                     &]
D:\test\test.tex:12: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [            &]
D:\test\test.tex:12: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [            &                     &]
D:\test\test.tex:12: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...                   &                     &]
D:\test\test.tex:12: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...                   &                     &]
D:\test\test.tex:13: Misplaced \noalign. [\midrule]
D:\test\test.tex:14: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [Obs.        &]
D:\test\test.tex:14: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [Obs.        &          74         &]
D:\test\test.tex:14: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...        74         &          74         &]
D:\test\test.tex:14: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...        74         &          74         &]
D:\test\test.tex:15: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [R$^2$       &]
D:\test\test.tex:15: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [R$^2$       &        0.29         &]
D:\test\test.tex:15: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...      0.29         &        0.29         &]
D:\test\test.tex:15: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...      0.29         &        0.32         &]
D:\test\regepr.tex:20: Misplaced \noalign. [\bottomrule]
D:\test\regepr.tex:21: Misplaced \crcr. [\end{tabular}]
D:\test\regepr.tex:21: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. [\end{tabular}]
D:\test\regepr.tex:21: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. [\end{tabular}]
D:\test\regepr.tex:21: Extra }, or forgotten $. [\end{tabular}]
D:\test\regepr.tex:21: Extra }, or forgotten $. [\end{tabular}]
D:\test\regepr.tex:21: Missing $ inserted. [\end{tabular}]
```

Comment: Is the difference only the first line in the first snippet?

Comment: Yes! Sorry I could have made that more clear. But why would the first line of `&\multicolumn{1}{c}{price}` ... matter?

Comment: I tried your code and can reproduce the error. It only appears when doing the input, not when putting the snippet directly to the tex file. Something seems to fail when the `\input` first tires to include a `\midrule`. And I have no idea why.

Comment: neither the error message nor the posted code has anything to do with `\include` so it would be good if you change the title to reflect the actual problem (and remove the include tag)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand: The error was caused by `\include` failing with `\midrule` so it seems important to mention it.

Comment: No, the error (and your example) use `\input` not `\include`, `\include` would be completely wrong here for multiple other reasons. `\input` almost works but just needs a bit of help, as I show in my answer.

Comment: Ok right. Sorry I mixed that up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\midrule`(like `\hline` and `\multicolumn`) has to be the first non-expandable command in the cell, any command even `\relax` or `{}` before it will cause it to give that error. LaTeX `\input` is not expandable so can not be used here.  You could use

```
\myinput test.tex
```

where `\myinput` is defined by

```
\makeatletter
\let\myinput\@@input
\makeatother
```